# Missing Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio after installation of Sql server Data Tools

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I have installed Microsoft Sql server data tools and still I'm unable to find the reporting tools. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple Reporting Services dlls in the project. I found out the correct one and the project works fine. Hope this helps for any other newbie!!

Comment: I've just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community and experiencing the same thing. Where can I check the multiple Reporting Services dlls in the project

Comment: @TimothyAnyona try in your references in Solution Explorer.